# maven class patching in external resource

Tags: java, maven, overwrite, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-shade-plugin

**Core topics** 
- Maven on linux and windows behaves completely different
- Patch specific class files within external jars

**Situation**
I have a multi-module java project with the following structure.

- Core (pom links the external dependencies)

  - Common
  - Services (Main class using the patched files)
  - modifications (Contains the patched class files)

The target is to overwrite certain class files from external dependencies defined as follows:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.knowm.xchange</groupId>
        <artifactId>xchange-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

The modification module uses therefore the same package structure like the classes in the dependency.

**Main problem**
If the application is executed in eclipse or a runnable jar file is created on windows, the modified files are used as it should be. If it is on the other hand built on Linux, the old files from the external repository are used.

**Investigations**
First, i used the maven-assembly-plugin in the version 2.2-beta-5 which is the default on windows together with maven 3.3.9. Using this configuration, the jar file contains the modified files. If a newer version for the assembly-plugin is used, it doesn't work anymore. On Linux, it never worked, it always used the unpatched files.

```
**** core.pom ****
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

```
**** services.pom ****
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>feedRunner</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <finalName>feedRunner</finalName>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>Priv.Services.Constructor.feedRunner</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Thus i tried using the maven-shade-plugin in the version 3.1.1 with maven in the version 3.3.9. On Windows it worked again but on linux the old files are used.

```
**** core.pom ****
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
       <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>${project.parent.basedir}/tmp</outputDirectory>
            <failOnError>false</failOnError>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>       
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${project.parent.basedir}/tmp</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
```

```
**** Services.pom ****
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
       <id>feedRunner</id>
       <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <outputFile>${project.parent.basedir}/jars/feedRunner.jar</outputFile>
          <outputDirectory>${project.parent.basedir}/tmp</outputDirectory>
          <transformers>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
              <manifestEntries>
                <Main-Class>Priv.Services.Constructor.feedRunner</Main-Class>
                <X-Compile-Source-JDK>${maven.compile.source}</X-Compile-Source-JDK>
                <X-Compile-Target-JDK>${maven.compile.target}</X-Compile-Target-JDK>
              </manifestEntries>
            </transformer>
          </transformers>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>       
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Why does linux behave so differently and how can i patch those files so a working runnable jar file can be created on both operating systems? I read some things aubout file excluding using shade, but how can this be done and is there no other solution without specifying all overwritten files?

It is also no solution (as i found on some topics) to download the full external dependency, modify the file and upload the changes to a repository and link that file.

Comment: Is there a reason why your are configuring so many parts of the plugins like outputDirectory ?

Comment: Do you have that project somewhere on github/bitbucket etc. available?

Comment: Yes. It was necessary, that the jars are generated in the desired location without any additional files in it. Just for beauty reasons in the output structure.

Comment: Not at the moment. I have to check out if i can produce a minimal example.